# Can Omnipay ( Paypal Checkout ) be used with membership signups / contributions using a CiviCRM Webform?

Tags: civimember, webform-civicrm, contributions, paypal, payment

I've been able to setup and configure Omnipay using Paypal checkout without issue.

However, I seem unable to use it with Civicrm webform to take membership payments.

The only reference to it can find is a comment on the announcement post in July that there are issues with it, does anybody have anymore information on support for it?

https://civicrm.org/blog/eileen/announcing-paypal-checkout

Thanks in advance for any help or workarounds.

Comment: So you've tried to set up a contribution form presumably? And what can you see on that? Can you elaborate?

Comment: When you get to the payment form it hits a JS errors as it seems unable to find values for CRM.vars.omnipay.client_id and CRM.vars.omnipay.currency.  I can't see these are set anywhere in the code. I still need to do some more digging but time limited. I need to rule out any customisations etc.

Comment: OK and you've looked here for an existing Issue or filed a new Issue? - https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.omnipaymultiprocessor/issues

Comment: OK right, an Issue already filed, at https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.omnipaymultiprocessor/issues/107

Comment: Thanks @JoeMcLaughlin, been a bit tied up.  Does seem like it's an on going issue, I'll keep an eye on the issue and work around it for now :).